# Read an element <elementname> from an XML file to DataGrid using WPF

Tags: xml, wpf, windows, xaml, visual-studio-2015

I have an XML file with elements in it. I need to fetch element names (i.e., Maruthi) to a DataGrid in WPF.

My XML file:

```
<Maruthi>
     <Maruthi_Alto>
              <Description>MINI</Description>
     </Maruthi_Alto>

     <Maruthi_Ciaz>
              <Description>Sedan</Description>
     </Maruthi_Ciaz>
 </Maruthi>
```

In XAML:

```
 <DataGrid
        DataContext="{StaticResource CarData}" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=}"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="Auto" 
        Name="dataGrid2" Margin="0,25,0,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn 
                Header="Car Name" 
                Binding="{Binding XPath=}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn 
                Header="Car Model" 
                Binding="{Binding XPath=}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn 
                Header="Description" 
                Binding="{Binding XPath=}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I am stuck on finding path detail in XAML.

Comment: Thanks jackfarm. . but in your ans u attached xml data in windows resource  , but the thing is i have around 70 diff xml files and i need to read all files element name so  is there any way solve this issue. .please help me out. .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   <Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="dataGridData" XPath="Cars">
            <x:XData>
                <Cars xmlns="">
                    <Maruthi>
                        <Maruthi_Alto>
                            <Description>MINI</Description>
                        </Maruthi_Alto>
                        <Maruthi_Ciaz>
                            <Description>Sedan</Description>
                        </Maruthi_Ciaz>
                    </Maruthi>
                </Cars>
            </x:XData>
        </XmlDataProvider>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid DataContext="{StaticResource dataGridData}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=*}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
           <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Car Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
           </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

Each row displays one XML element, each element has a 'Name' property, I just bind to this property: `Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"`.

Comment: Could you please explain why your answer solves OP's question?

Comment: @Tomasz Kowalczyk I wrote the explain in the answer.